# Do any microcontrollers allow steering of inputs to outputs?

Tags: microcontroller, buffer

Are there any MCUs which allow input signals to be connected (by software) to outputs?

The main requirement is that should not involve sampling (either by MCU code or SCTimers) as this limits the speed of the steered signal to that of the MCU.

The signals I'm looking at steering are 480Mbit USB2, which is faster than common MCUs.

I suppose I'm looking for a sort of MCU with built in buffers, as such a circuit could be made from a common MCU and a couple of buffers.

Comment: Maybe a CPLD or FPGA would be better for such a task.

Comment: I vaguely recall a few with comparators that may have had an output option. Perhaps worth checking up.

Comment: Or the entire range of high speed USB multiplexers that exist.  How about http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/609/ADG772-878543.pdf

Comment: @Mario What would a CPLD offer that a MCU and a couple of buffers wouldn't?

Comment: @Wossname - Thanks, I did not know about USB-specific multiplexers, make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose I would recommend the use of a USB 2.0 Multiplexer IC.

Many are available, a typical one that supports 480MBit USB is the Analog Devices ADG772...

http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/609/ADG772-878543.pdf

Or the Texas Instruments TPS65981

http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tps65981

There are many others though and the price range reflects the number of features available.  If you require Host or Device functionality will dictate some of the design requirements as will "OTG" and "dedicated charging".

Follow the datasheets' PCB layout recommendations for whichever chip you choose.